# android compilation error in Eclipse

Tags: android

Android requires .class compatibility set to 5.0 or 6.0. Found '1.7' instead. Please use Android Tools > Fix Project Properties.

Comment: Have you tried `Android Tools > Fix Project Properties` ?

Comment: this seems like an issue with java compiler. try changing your project settings in proprties.

Answer (score 2):

Right click on the project select project properties.

goto java compiler and select java 1.6 instead of 1.7

Answer (score 1):

This is nothing. This is because you have not set your Updated jre 1.7. Instead you have selected 1.6. But 1.7 is a updated jre 1.7.

So select it. And after that Right click on project -> Properties-> Android Tools > Fix Project Properties.

After that clean your project and run again.

Answer (score 1):

right click on project -
java compiler - and on right hand side there is option to set java version.

over there you can set 1.7 if already installed.

or you set installed version of java over there